# Help with an algebraic geometry result

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, group-actions, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

I am studying this part of algebraic geometry and I have come to this proposition. I understand the basic idea well but there are two details that escape me.

> Proposition: Let $G$ be a finite group acting linearly over $X$,
> affine closed. Then, exsist an affine closed $Y$ and a surjective
> morphism $\psi:X \rightarrow Y$ such that $K[Y]=K[X]^G$ and $\psi^*$
> is the inclusion map $K[X]^G \subset K[X]$.  Furthermore, for all
> $p,q$ in $X$  $$\psi(q)=\psi(p) \iff \exists g \in G :\;\;\;q=gp$$

> Proof of the second part (within my notes)
>
> $\Leftarrow$  Let $p,q$ points in $\mathbb{A}^n$ such that $\;\exists g \in G :\;q=gp. \;\;$ For all $f \in K[X]^G$ we have $f(q)=f(gp)=f^g(p)=f(p)$, so
> $$f(\psi(q))=\psi^*(f(q))=f(q)=f(p)=\psi^*(f(p))=f(\psi(p))$$ **Then**
> $\psi(p)=\psi(q)$.
>
> $\Rightarrow$ Let $p,q$ points in $\mathbb{A}^n$ such that
> $\psi(p)=\psi(q)$. Supposte that $\not\exists g \in G: \;\; q=gp$.
>
> **Choice** $f \in I_X(p)$  [i.e.$f\in K[X], f(p)=0$]   but $f(gq)\neq0
> > \;\; \forall g \in G$
>
> So $h=\prod_{g\in G} f^g$ is such that $h \in K[X]^G$, $h(p)=0$
> because $f$ is a factor, $h(q)=\prod_{g\in G}    f^g(q)=\prod_{g\in G}
> > f(gq) \neq 0$
>
> This implies $h(\psi(q))=\psi^*(h(q))=(h(q))\neq
> > h(p)=\psi^*(h(p))=h(\psi(p))$. Absurd because $\psi(p)=\psi(q)$.

---

I didn't understand these two steps:

1. Why $f(\psi(p))=f(\psi(q))$ implies $\psi(p)=\psi(q)$?
   I don't understand how this works, since f is non-injective
2. What guarantees me that such a function exists?
   I tried to prove this with a proof by contradiction but I couldn't.

---

For 2.  had thought of proceeding like this:

Being $O(p)$ and $O(q)$, i.e. orbits of $p$ and $q$, G-invariant and disjoint closed of X, their respective ideals are G-invariants:
$$f(p)=0 \Rightarrow f \in I(O(p))\Rightarrow Z(f) \subset Z(I(O(p)))=O(p)$$
$$f(gq)=f^g(q)=0 \Rightarrow f^g \in I(O(q))\Rightarrow f \in I(O(q)) \Rightarrow q \in Z(f) \subset O(p)$$
absurd since $q \in O(q)$ and $O(q)\cap O(p)=\emptyset$

**All this only works if and oly if $O(p)$ and $O(q)$ are closed**

**BUT CAN I SAY THAT $O(p)$ AND $O(q)$ ARE CLOSED?**

Comment: 1. This title is hopelessly vague. Please improve it by making it more specific - readers should be able to get a good sense of your question just by reading the title. 2. You posted something very similar earlier today and deleted it before posting this. Please don't do that in the future - edit your post instead.

Comment: So everything boils down to the first part, which you did *not* quote. That's the key.

Comment: @KReiser You are right, I had already entered the question but I never received any answer. I noticed that many theory questions, which instead receive answers, have as their title "help with a result" and so I thought the problem was the title, so I deleted everything and rewrobed it. I don't know how to get help from someone.

Comment: The first part doesn't have a real demonstration (otherwise I would have inserted it). It simply derives from a of group actions that says: If $A$ is a finitely generated $K-$algebra and $G$ is a finite group, then $A^G$ is a finit. gen. $K-$algebra. Since in our case $G$ is a finite group and $K[X]$ is a  finitely generated $K-$algebra, then $K[X]^G$ is a fin. gen. $K-$algebra and therefore there is an affine close $Y$ as the first part says. The whole demonstration focuses only on the second part, which is the 'new' thing, that not derive directly from previous results. @TedShifrin

Comment: I can certainly appreciate the desire for help. There's no way to guarantee getting it, but there are some things to do that can improve your chances. First, peruse [how to ask a good  question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on meta - if your question is of higher quality, it's more likely to get a response. Next, you may have to wait a bit: for questions in more specialized subjects, it's not uncommon for an answer to take days instead of hours to appear.

Comment: In that edit you've made, the inclusions go the other way. $f\in I(O(p))$ implies that $Z(f)\supset O(p)$, because taking the set of zeroes doesn't preserve inclusions, but rather it reverses them.

The orbits are closed, though: they are finite sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is about varieties over an algebraically closed field. If I'm right, then the answers are:

1. This proves that for **every** $f\in K[X]^G$, $f(\psi(p))=f(\psi(q))$. One of these functions is not necessarily injective, but the first part of the proposition says that $K[X]^G$ is an affine closed variety, i.e. a closed subset in some affine space. Therefore, there are functions $f_1,\ldots ,f_N$ such that $(f_1,\ldots ,f_N):Y\to \mathbb A^N$ is a closed embedding (in particular injective), and since $(f_1,\ldots ,f_N)(\psi(p)) = (f_1,\ldots ,f_N)(\psi(q))$, this means that $\psi(p)=\psi(q)$.
2. We are proving the contrapositive. If $p\neq gq$ for all $q$, then $\psi(p)\neq \psi(q)$. The first claim we want to prove is that if $p$ is not in the finite set $G\cdot q = \{gq\colon g\in G\}$, then there is a function $f$ that vanishes at $p$ but nowhere in $G\cdot q$. In fact, we can take a linear function: say we have coordinates of $\mathbb A^n$, $(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$, such that $p$ is the origin. Then we are looking for a function of the form $f = \sum a_ix_i$. The condition that $f(gq)=0$ is a nonzero linear equation in the $a_i$'s. If we say that $\overline{a} = (a_1,\ldots ,a_n)\in \mathbb A^n$, to $gq$ corresponds a hyperplane $H_g$ in $\mathbb A^n$, and $f(gq)\neq 0\Leftrightarrow \overline a\notin H_g$. So, there exists $\overline{a}$ such that $f(gq)\neq 0$ for all $g$ if and only if $\mathbb A^n\setminus (\bigcup_{g\in G} H_g)$ is not empty. But affine space is not a finite union of hyperplanes*, so we are done.

*(It's crucial that $K$ is algebraically closed, and therefore infinite: if $K$ is finite, then affine space is a finite union of hyperplanes)

---

Why affine space is not a finite union of hyperplanes: We prove this for $\mathbb A^n$ by induction on $n$. For $n=1$, hyperplanes are points and if $K$ is infinite, then we are done. Now, for general $n$, say our hyperplanes are $H_1,\ldots , H_m$. There are infinitely many planes parallel to $H_1$ (because the field is infinite), so one of them, say $H'$, must be different from all of $H_1,\ldots ,H_m$. This means that $H'\cap H_j\subsetneq H'$ for all $j$. $H'$ is an affine space of dimension $n-1$, and each $H'\cap H_j$ is either a hyperplane in $H_j$ or it is empty (as it can't equal $H'$). By induction, there is a point $p\in H'$ not contained in any of the hyperplanes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention and your answer, I would have the following doubts:
For point 1: $K[X]^G=K[Y]$ and in the first part it has been shown that $Y$ is closed affine so $Y\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ so exists closed embedding but the regular functions on $Y$ (i.e f in $K[Y]$, as required) are not of the form $Y\rightarrow K$?
For point 2: I cannot understand where the fact that $f \in I_x(p)$ is exploited, moreover, the result "affine space is not a finite union of hyperplanes" is not known to me.

Comment: I added how to prove that affine space is not a finite union of hyperplanes. I don't understand your first question. Like I said before, I don't know if you are working with varieties or schemes. If I'm still assuming you are working with varieties, then $\mathbb A^1=K$, so a regular function is a map to $\mathbb A^1$, and $n$ regular functions together give you a map to $\mathbb A^n$

Comment: The first point is really very clear to me thanks to you. 
On the second point, I still have my doubts. Or rather, your process is clear to me, but it seems strange to me that in the demonstration we have to use (taking it for granted) a result not previously demonstrated (affine space is not a finite union of hyperplanes).

Comment: I also found this result as an example (example 11) on the book [link](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~egoins/seminar/shafarevich.pdf)  and also here it is for granted. So it seems strange to me. 
I am thinking of a demonstration that does not exploit too many unmentioned elements. 
Since the orbits are closed, perhaps one could take advantage of the 2.2 lemma of [link](https://web.northeastern.edu/iloseu/Jose_S16.pdf) which has an almost immediate proof. But I don't understand why the fact that the orbits are disjointed implies the surietivity of that map.

Comment: In Shafarevich's book that's considered known at that point, most likely. In section 3.1 it's shown that affine space is irreducible, and therefore it is not a union of proper closed subvarieties, such as hyperplanes. Or if they assume that the reader knows about dimensions, you can conclude that a union of hyperplanes has dimension $n-1$ while affine space has dimension $n$, so they can never be equal.